# SQL Server : convert nvarchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have a set of dates which are in the current format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000
```

e.g.

```
2016-04-15 13:30:00.000
```

I have put them into a SQL Server table as `nvarchar(MAX)` but I need to convert them to `datetime` in a view.

I have tried the following pieces of code but neither work:

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), start_date, 120) AS start_date1 

CAST(RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), LEFT(start_date, 20), 120), 19) AS datetime) AS start_date1
```

Comment: Why are you storing them as nvarchar(MAX) ?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: It was easier to bring the csv data into the table via a SSIS package as nvarchar than doing a data conversion. No matter what I tried I couldn't get the data conversion to work so thought it would be easier to convert it when creating a view.

Comment: SQL Server 2014 @nscheaffer

Comment: I'd just use CONVERT(datetime,start_date)

Answer (score 3):

```
Declare @String nvarchar(max) = '2016-04-15 13:30:00.000'
Select cast(@String as datetime)
```

Return 2016-04-15 13:30:00.000

Comment: This is `dateformat` dependant what actual result you get so the OP might need to `set dateformat` first.

Comment: Agreed, I did not consider that